# std::wstring in ChaiScript

Tags: wstring, chaiscript

I am a beginner for ChaiScript.

I try to use `std::wstring` type in ChaiScript.

std::string type is works well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp>

int main()
{
    chaiscript::ChaiScript chai(chaiscript::Std_Lib::library());

    std::cout << chai.eval<std::function<int (std::string)> >(
        "fun(s){"       
        "   if(s==\"aaa\"){"
        "       print(\"1\");"      
        "   }"      
        "   if(s[1]=='b'){"
        "       print(\"2\");"
        "   }"
        "   return 3;"
        "}"
    )(std::string("abcd")); 
}

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t1.exe
2
3
```

`std::wstring` type raises an exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp>

int main()
{
    chaiscript::ChaiScript chai(chaiscript::Std_Lib::library());

    std::cout << chai.eval<std::function<int (std::wstring)> >(
        "fun(s){"       
        "   if(s==\"aaa\"){"
        "       print(\"1\");"      
        "   }"      
        "   if(s[1]=='b'){"
        "       print(\"2\");"
        "   }"
        "   return 3;"
        "}"
    )(std::wstring(L"abcd"));
}
```

> D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t2.exe
>   
>  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'chaiscript::exception::eval_error'
>   
>  what():  Error: "Can not find appropriate '==' operator." With parameters: (NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE, const string)
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   
>  Please contact the application's support team for more information.

ChaiScript git version and mingw-w64 builds 5.1.0 are used.

```
g++ t2.cpp -std=c++14 -O2 -Os -Wall -mthreads -o t2.exe -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -Id:\myprj\chaiscript_git\include -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

It is same in vs2013.

How can I use `std::wstring` type in ChaiScript?

Answer (score 3):

`std::wstring` is just like any other type in ChaiScript - you have to tell ChaiScript how you want to use it.

In this case, you are trying to perform an `==` comparison, but have not provided ChaiScript with a `operator==(const std::wstring &, const std::wstring &)` function for it to use.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the existing code for `std::string` and expose all of the same functionality.

for example:

```
#include <chaiscript/dispatchkit/bootstrap_stl.hpp>

chai.add(chaiscript::bootstrap::standard_library::string_type<std::wstring>("wstring"));
```

For reference, see the [bootstrap.hpp code](https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/ba492308f4f3284f045d7bed8c5ef64ebc0f50c7/include/chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp#L45) that initializes `std::string`.